# Android TranslateAnimation strange problems

Tags: android, android-animation, translate-animation

As a part of my project I need to create chessboard (with possibility to move pieces) for Android devices. All worked perfectly well till I've decided to add animation to pieces movements. Now the problem is as follows: if the code looks like the one you may see below, behaviour is the following:

- firstly, piece X moves as I expect;
- but when I start animating the next move the image of piece X appears (although respective ImageView stays empty) in the cell where it stayed before the previous move. I mean, its copy appears in the previous position while it is staying in its current cell at the same time;

```java
final ImageView movingPiece = (ImageView) findViewById(prevCellId);
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, dx, 0, dy);
animation.setDuration(500);
animation.setFillBefore(true);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        setPiece(prevCellId, null);
        setPiece(newCellId, chosenPiece);
        movingPiece.clearAnimation();
    }

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }
});
movingPiece.startAnimation(animation);
```

In order to make some points concerning the code clear: `setPiece` gets id of the cell to put some content into and an object to put into the cell. Inside the method I replace the respective ImageView ImageResource with the picture of the respective piece or with the `android.R.color.transparent` (if the second parameter is `null`).

Please explain me what is happening and how I can achieve the desired behaviour (I mean, without strange reappearing of pieces on their previous positions).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

dx and dy are probably wrong calculated 
(if you use getY on different lines).

And remove fillBefore() and fillAfter()

I have recreated your situation wirh Buttons and it works for me, this is the sourcecode

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.animation.*;
import android.graphics.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int id, d, x, y;
    private Button selected;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        d = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/10;

        LinearLayout grid = new LinearLayout(this);
        grid.setClipChildren(false);
        grid.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        for(int c=0; c<10; c++) addRow(grid);
        setContentView(grid);

    }

    private void addRow(LinearLayout grid) {
        x=0;
        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
        for(int c=0; c<10; c++) addCell(row);
        row.setClipChildren(false);
        row.setClipToOutline(false);
        grid.addView(row);
        y+=d;
    }

    private void addCell(LinearLayout row) {
        Button cell = new Button(this) {

            int _x = x;
            int _y = y;

            @Override
            public float getX() {
                return _x;
            }
            @Override
            public float getY() {
                return _y;
            }
        };
        cell.setText(""+(id++));
        cell.setTextSize(10);
        cell.setClipToOutline(false);
        cell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    Button bt = (Button)v;

                    //select source
                    if(selected==null) {
                        selected=bt;
                        return;
                    }

                    //deselect pressing again
                    if(selected==bt) {
                        selected=null;
                        return;
                    }

                    //selected source and target
                    moveTo(bt);



                }
            });
        row.addView(cell, d, d);

        x+=d;
    }

    private void moveTo(final Button target) {

        final Button movingPiece = selected;

        float dx = target.getX() - movingPiece.getX();
        float dy = target.getY() - movingPiece.getY();

        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, dx, 0, dy);
        animation.setDuration(500);
        //animation.setFillBefore(true);
        //animation.setFillAfter(true);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    setPiece(target, selected.getText().toString());
                    setPiece(selected, null);

                    //movingPiece.clearAnimation();

                    selected = null;
                }

                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }

                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }
            });
        movingPiece.startAnimation(animation);
    }

    private void setPiece(Button bt, String txt) {
        if(txt==null) bt.setText("");
        bt.setText(txt);
    }

}
```

I hope you will find this useful.

How you calculate dx and dy ?